# ActionScript 3 CamRoll: Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have some ActionScript code that looks like it should work, but I get this error upon clicking the "capture_btn" button.

> Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=Error #2037: Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful.
>     at movember_1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[movember_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:8]
>     at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
>     at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
>     at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
>     at runtime::AppRunner/run()
>     at ADLAppEntry/run()
>     at global/runtime::ADLEntry()**

Below is my ActionScript:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.CameraRoll;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
banner_mc.visible=false;
var mediaSource:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera("0");
cam.setMode(tabletCam.width, tabletCam.height, 15, true);
tabletCam.attachCamera(cam);
capture_btn.addEventListenerTouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,captureImage);
function captureImage(e:TouchEvent){
    capture_btn.visible=false;
    banner_mc.visible=true;
    var screenCapture:BitmapData = new BitmapData(tabletCam.width,tabletCam.height);
    screenCapture.draw(stage);
    mediaSource.addBitmapData(screenCapture);
    mediaSource.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSave);
}
function onSave(e:Event) {
    capture_btn.visible=true;
    banner_mc.visible=false;
}
```

Comment: I noticed you used the word "click", but the CameraRoll feature is only supported on mobile. Did you try 'trace(CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData);' ?

Comment: Thanks for the followup.  Yes, BitmapData is supported.

Comment: The error refers to `cam.setMode(tabletCam.width, tabletCam.height, 15, true);` line. Can you verify if `tabletCam` exists at that point? Also, maybe `cam` does not support `setMode`.